# ant design - datepicker with time saves with 00:00:00 as time?

Tags: reactjs, date, datetime, antd

So im using antd for my design in frontend with React. I want to store an object with datetime in database. I see that antd's Datepicker is capable of that but it always stores in my database with 00:00:00 as time. Date, month year are ok.

I tried to use `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')` and save it like that in the database but i get error `Uncaught TypeError: date.clone is not a function`

This is my datepicker. The issue raises when i try to use my setPickedFrom function from useState. Why is this a problem?

```
<DatePicker
                allowClear={false}
                placeholder="Rent from: "
                // format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
                disabledDate={disabledDate}
                onChange={(e) => onDateClear(e, "from")}
                onOk={(date) =>
                  setPickedFrom(
                    moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                    "to"
                  )
                }
                value={pickedFrom ? pickedFrom : null}
                showTime
                className="date-picker2"
              />
```

Saving the dates function (Create Rent)

```
  const createRent = () => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/rents/createRent", {
        date_from: pickedFrom,
        date_to: pickedUntil,
        userId: user.id,
        itemId: currentItem.id,
      })
      .then(() => {
        showNotification("Item rented");
        setCurrentItem({});
        setDifference(null);
        setIsModalVisible(false);
        setPickedFrom(null);
        setPickedUntil(null);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        showNotification(e.response.data.message, "error");
      });
  };
```

I just need to find a way to save date and time in my database in the following format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss) because this is the accepted format for my database.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```
const onOk = (value) => {
    console.log("onOk: ", moment().format());
    console.log("onOk: ", typeof value);
    console.log("onOk: ", value.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
  };
<DatePicker format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" showTime={true} onOk={onOK}/>
```

Comment: Hmm...but how does this help me save the correct format in my database? this just prints it out in the console?

Comment: @MarkoMarchisio you could do anything the 'value'

Comment: It still saves in my database without the time. For example, instead of it saving as 2021-11-05 00:00:00 , i want it to save as 2021-11-05 09:07:32. So, the issue is that somehow in the process of setting the "value" tom my state, the time part of moment() is lost. I tried saving it formatted ('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") using the moment().format() but i get the error TypeError: date.clone is not a function

Comment: @MarkoMarchisio please share the function you used to save time to database

Comment: I edited the post, added the function

Comment: @MarkoMarchisio I have edited the function. This will help